# why does my postback in Chrome not refresh my page

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have a postback that should refresh my page and reload page. When the page reloads it should display an image or an uploaded link or an uploaded document link or something. This works great when I run locally, but when I have deployed the same code to my host server, the page reloads with blanks, and the user must hit refresh to see the results. the following code snippet asks the user to upload an image, and then performs an update:

markup:

```
  <form id="updateLogo" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                        <h5 class="red"><b>(Image sizes are limited to 1 Megabyte)</b></h5>
                        Select File:
                        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="file" id="file" required="required" />
                        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="communityId" id="communityId" value="@ViewBag.CommunityId" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                        Current Profile Image:
                        <img src="@ViewBag.LogoImage" class="img-responsive img-circle" style="width:150px; height:150px" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" class="btn btn-habitat" id="updtLogo">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

javascript with ajax :

$("#updtLogo").click(function () {
        // Host

```
    var hostname = location.hostname;
    var host = '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["hostroot"]';
    if (hostname == "localhost")
        host = "";

    // New Form data including the newly uploaded file
    var formSerialized = $("#updateLogo").serializeArray();
    var formdata = new FormData();

    var logofile = $("#file")[0].files[0];

    // Supporting Assets (i.e. uploaded files go here)
    for (i = 0; i < $("#file")[0].files.length; i++) {
        formdata.append("File", $("#file")[0].files[i]);
    }

    $.each(formSerialized, function (i, field) {
        formdata.append(field.name, field.value);
    });

    var communityId = $("#communityId").val();
    var fileLogo = $("#file").val();

    // Only allow if file size is less than 1MB
    if (logofile.size < (1024 * 1024)) {

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: host + "/Communities/UploadLogo/" + communityId + "?logo=" + fileLogo,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formdata,
            success: function () {
                console.log('success!!');
            }

        });
        window.location.reload();
    } else {
        var errorMsg = 3;
        $(".modal-dialog").css({
            "left": 0,
            "top": 200,
        });

        $(".modal-body").css({
            "background-color": "green"
        })

        $(".modal-title").text("Error Uploading Logo Image");

        var url = host + "/Communities/ErrorMessageDialog/" + communityId + "?errorMsg=" + errorMsg;

        $("#inviteDialog").load(url, function () {
            $("#inviteModal").modal("show");
        })
    }
    return false;
});
```

MVC ActionResult

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult UploadLogo(int id, string logo)
{

    // Uploaded data files go here
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
    var logoFile = file.FileName != null ? file.FileName : logo;
    if (logoFile != null || logoFile != "")
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(logoFile);
        var host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["hostroot"];
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)
            host = "";

        var communityId = id;
        //    var fileName = file.FileName;
        var directory = Server.MapPath("~/CommunityStorage/" + communityId + "/Logo/");
        var virtualPath = host + "/CommunityStorage/" + communityId + "/Logo/";

        // Create a new directory for the community if it does not exist based on their community id
        if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
        }

        var path = Path.Combine(directory, fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);

        // Save file path to the Communities Table
        var community = db.Communities.Where(x => x.CommunityId == communityId).SingleOrDefault();
        if (community == null)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "login");

        // Update the Logo in the communities table
        community.LogoPath = virtualPath + fileName;
        db.SaveChanges();

    }

    return View();

}
```

Comment: just seeing `window.location.reload()` after your ajax call is a red flag to me, you will never get to your callback before you clear all the data you had on your page have you tried calling functions / doing things in the callback without refreshing the page?

Comment: Suggestions? I am all ears, I know there has to be a better technique

Comment: can I just do a return RedirecttoAction from my controller, I might try this

Comment: I'm not sure specifically what you want to do after you get the data, but the typical pattern for ajax follows as: `$.ajax({ ... success: function(data) { /* Do stuff here */ } });`. If you need to reload the page, do it in the callback: an external request (server) will most definitely take longer than a local request, which would explain why you may need to refresh the page on the server unlike your local deployment

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your assistance

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> the typical pattern for ajax follows as:
>
> `$.ajax({ ... success: function(data) { /* Do stuff here */ } });`

If you are looking to reload the page after you receive your data do so in the callback like so:

```
$.ajax({
     ... 
    success: function(data) { 
        window.location.reload(); 
     } 
 });
```

Be careful when reloading the page: JavaScript data doesn't persist after page reload unless you're using cookies / caching.

Comment: My load data comes from a database, not javascript data

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel that works just as well! I added it more for anyone who may see this and not realize why it can work here and not for them